# OpenCV and Tensorflow Colour issue (Most probably due to channels maybe?)

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, colors, bgr

I was using this pytorch model for real-ESRGAN. It was giving good results:

[image: Expected image]

Now I converted this model to tensorflow one. Now when I use this, I am getting image super resoluted (I reached to that conclusion due to image size of output) but its color channels are in very weird condition:

[image]

I am using opencv to take input and then model to process it. I feel issue is with BGR and RGB of OpenCV and Tensorflow but using cv2.COLOR_BGRTORGB not helping.

Any idea how to solve this?

This is my code:

```
from pyexpat import model
import tensorflow as tf
import os.path as osp
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch



test_img_folder = './images/*'

model = tf.saved_model.load("./RealESRGAN_1/")

idx = 0
for path in glob.glob(test_img_folder):
    idx += 1
    base = osp.splitext(osp.basename(path))[0]
    print(idx, base)
    # read images
    img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    print(img.shape)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.imshow('Input',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    img = np.transpose(img, (2,0,1))
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    img = tf.dtypes.cast(img, tf.float32)
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(x = img)
    
    output = output['sum'].numpy()
    output = output[0, :, :, :]
    output = np.transpose(output, (1,2,0))
    cv2.imwrite('./results/{:s}_rlt.png'.format(base), output)
```

Comment: sure, that's an rgb - bgr problem. show code, so we can try to find out, where it happens, please

Comment: Try `cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR` before saving the image

Comment: @JeruLuke can you please be more specific? Before saving means? Which line?

Comment: @siddharthpatel Before the line containing `cv2.imwrite`

Comment: @JeruLuke Not working

Comment: @siddharthpatel Please share what you modified and where

Comment: @JeruLuke I added this line just before last line:
    cv2.cvtColor(output, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

Comment: @siddharthpatel I am unable to reproduce your situation. Can you share the GitHub link to your model?

Comment: @JeruLuke Here: https://github.com/Siddharth1India/SuperResolution

You can reproduce error in test.py

Comment: @siddharthpatel What is `pyexpat`? How do you install it?

Comment: @JeruLuke thanks for all help, turned out issue was with .pb file, made changes and now it is working fine.
Issue was not with rgb or bgr.

Comment: @siddharthpatel Welcome to Stackoverflow! Do you want to share your solution here for others? You can write an answer to your own question.

Comment: Hey @Markus, I am not sure how it was happening, I just made pb file again (without making any change in code) and it worked.